Is it efficient to use realloc to free up small chunks of memory C++
I'm writing an application that generates a bunch of n strings (bit)length l and then does a comparison between all possible pairs.
I first allocate memory for n strings of length l
char* pStr = (char*)(malloc(n * l)); 

Then I run my comparison of the last char of the last string with the last char of all other strings and store my results. After this I technically do not need to store that char anymore so I could use pStr = realloc(pStr, n*l - sizeof(char*)) to free up that memory.
Im wondering if this makes sense to do, say for every char, or for every string after the whole string has been compared. If you increase size of the pointer and realloc can't do so contiguously it will copy the memory to a new location instead which isn't very efficient. Could something like this ever happen when shrinking the allocated memory or not since it can always be contiguous?
Also am I assuming correctly that the memory freed when resizing using realloc is the last char in the pointer? If so would there be any way to instead remove the first char and shift the remaining ones to the pointer address?

C and C++ are different languages, which one you really use ? If it's C++ (based on the title) - please remove the C tag.

Also if it's C++ - why do you use malloc family at all ? C++ has new/delete, and better still - containers and smart pointers.

"Could something like this ever happen when shrinking the allocated memory or not since it can always be contiguous?" yes it could, it's not specified. As a rule of thumb, fewer reallocs are better than reallocs for every tiny change of size.

pStr = realloc(pStr, n*l - sizeof(char*)) is wrong because there is no way to correctly handle the memory when realloc fails. Also as commented you need to have a very strong argument to use *alloc and free in C++ but it is missing from the question. In C where *alloc is typically used, the correct way is tmp=realloc(ptr, ...); if(!tmp){...; return ...;} ptr=tmp;.

Is it just me or does "a bunch of n strings (bit)length" make no sense whatsoever?

Apart from figuring out whether you want to use C or C++, you should also reconsider what type of data structure you want to use. If you expect to frequently add or remove elements from your dataset, consider laying out your data in a linked list rather than an array. While a linked list will not be as compact in terms of memory as a simple array, especially for such a base type as char, it will simplify your code in the long run.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76522412/4165552 ; and in principle: "if this makes sense to do" - no, it doesn't make sense to do anything that you proposed, unless you have some very strong argument for that (but it's missing from the question). Use std::string with some container, if needed, and if you need only a portion of a string you can take a view.

Many memory allocators will not do uneven sizes, so might only handle perhaps 8, 16, and 32 bytes, but not 31 or 27. So realloc to free 1, or 6, bytes might just have no effect.

Since you are trying to free a single char, it seems that realloc(pStr, n*l - sizeof(char)) is what you want (char not char*). To me this is very obviously not a good thing to do.

As far as I can see no guarantee is made that calling realloc with a size smaller than the original will not cause a new block to be allocated and the memory copied across. One can imagine an allocator that places blocks of different sizes in different data structures, so shrinking a block may move that block from one address to another.

Assuming the memory consumption goes down as you are doing this (which isn't even a guarantee) who is to benefit from that?

Note that in C++ malloc is hardly ever used, and even new/delete are not recommended. For your scenario C++ has placement new where you can preallocate a large buffer and manage smaller chuncks within that memory.  This will at least shield the rest of your code from memory fragmentation.

Unless you are allocating memory in-between the reallocations, there is no chance that you will run out of memory, so do not need to be reallocating anything.
If you are running out of memory, then freeing up tiny chunks is probably not going to save you.
Reallocations to a smaller size will typically happen in-place, although no guarantees are given about that.  (And yes, you are assuming correctly, that it is always the end of the block that gets chopped off.)
When you reallocate a block to a smaller size, what typically happens under the hood is that the standard library first sees if it can create a new free block right after the end of the newly reallocated block to hold the freed up memory. Every free block begins with a header, which typically contains two pointers (doubly-linked free list) and one length; this is a whole 4 + 4 + 4 = 12 bytes on a 32-bit system, double that on a 64-bit system.
If the number of bytes you are releasing is smaller than that, then the standard library cannot create a new free block, so one of the following two things will happen:

Either the reallocation will result in zero memory being freed, or
The reallocated block will be moved elsewhere, with all the overhead that this represents.

Generally, dynamic memory allocation (and reallocation, and freeing,) is expensive, so the fewer of it you do, the better.
For C++ applications that do a lot of dynamic memory allocation, one of the biggest problems is memory fragmentation, and the more you churn the memory around, the more fragmentation you will have.
So, bottom line is:
For a vaguely defined situation such as this, there is no definitive answer, but the reallocations you are contemplating are not likely to be efficient.  As a matter of fact, most chances are that they are going to be very inefficient.
P.S.
If you are an application programmer, and you find yourself thinking of saving memory of the order of bytes here and there, or saving processing time of the order of clock cycles here and there, the savings are never worth the mental effort.


am I assuming correctly that the memory freed when resizing using realloc is the last char in the pointer? If so would there be any way to instead remove the first char and shift the remaining ones to the pointer address?

No, your assumption is not correct.

Could something like this ever happen when shrinking the allocated memory or not since it can always be contiguous?

You can try to use this Trial Demo Code to dynamically allocate an array of characters, and then remove a part from the front while shrinking the size of the allocated memory accordingly.
